# How to check if the symlink as well as directory exists in linux

Tags: linux, bash, symlink

I have the symlink

```
data -> /application/madat/gold/gold_lock/Methods96/../data
```

I would like to check if the symlink exists and the directory exists using shell script.

I have tried this:

```
#!/bin/bash
if [[ -h data && data -ef application/madat/gold/gold_lock/Methods96/../data ]]; then echo it exists; else echo it does not; fi
```

But it doesnot work..

Any lead is appreciated.

Comment: `readlink` and `readlink -f` might be of use

Answer (score 6):

You can try something like this

```
if [[ -L "data" && -d "$(readlink data )" ]]; then
  echo "both exists"
else
  echo "symlink or directory does not exist"
fi
```

`-L` will test if it's a symlink, then `-d` will look if the directory behind the symlink exists.

If there can be other symlinks in the path of the directory, use `readlink -f`

Update: forgot to say that `-h`and `-L` are equivalent but I find the second easier to remember. This was tested on ubuntu, btw.

Comment: Actually, it has no of symlink like that where only color like gold changes. and your code gives no output

Comment: it should be the same on centos (I don't have access to one). I updated with a `else` part.  Is that what you meant ? I just tested this again successfully. If the updated version is not ok, can you explain again what the problem is ?

Comment: its giving result in else part. but symlink and directory exists

Comment: can you try with `-d "$(readlink -f data )"`?  Otherwise, I would like to know if it's the -L or -d that fails

Comment: then I don't understand.  I just tested this on a RH5.7 with success.  You are, of course, running that in the directory where data link is located?  Can you tell me whether it's -L or -d that does not work ?  What does this snippet gives you: `[[ ! -L "data" ]] && { echo "not a symlink"; }; readlink -e data`.  If the symlink does not exists you will see the echo, if the readlink exists you will see your directory, if it does not nothing will shown.

Comment: You don't need to use `readlink`; if `data` is a symlink to a directory, then `[ -d data ]` will succeed. That's why `-L` exists, to allow you to distinguish between the symlink itself and what it references.